# What exactly is match.url in React Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I see in the React Router docs that you pass into components the `match` prop, and you can call `match.url`, but you never seem to actually pass in anything to the component. So what exactly is match and where are you getting it from?

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match

You get `match` in the props, usually when your component is called by a Route you will get it, and you can pass it down to other components as regular props to extract or use the information.

`location` is also very useful when interacting with react-router. I usually use match to do rendering and redirecting depending on the `isExact` flag, and location to have the actual URL that the browser has.

Answer (score 0):

See match() is pure JavaScript's String property. So if match is used in JSX, then react also made it's custom property `match` so that it does not conflict with main `match()` and it is global object for React Router.

I have faced this issue and worked out knowing that don't need to worry that it should be passed in props or state. In fact it is custom property in JSX which does not conflict with actual String.prototype's property.

So without messing your head, just think it as of `match()` property that is from global Object specially used in React Router