# Conditional rendering on React routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have several routes where different components are being rendered depending on the path as the following in my `App.js`

```
  <Route
  path="/spaces"
  render={({ match: { url } }) => (
    <>
        <Route path={[`${url}`, `${url}/members`, `${url}/about`, `${url}/admin`]} component={Spaces} exact />
    </>
  )}
/>

<Route
  path="/profile"
  render={({ match: { url } }) => (
    <>
      <Route path={[`${url}`, `${url}/comments`, `${url}/spaces`, `${url}/cloud`]} component={Spaces} exact />
    </>
  )}
/>
```

In my `Space.js` component I have created a conditional rendering depending on the url, so when the user is in for example `/spaces/members` or `/spaces/members/` a component will be rendered etc ..

```
function Spaces({ match }) {
  let path = `${match.url}`;
  let Content;
  let admin;
  let profile;

  if (path == '/spaces/members/' || path == '/spaces/members') {
    Content = <SpaceMembers />;
  } else if (path == '/spaces/' || path == '/spaces') {
    Content = <SpaceContent />;
  } else if (path == '/spaces/about' || path == '/spaces/about/') {
    Content = <SpaceAbout />;
  }  else if (path == '/spaces/admin' || path == '/spaces/admin/') {
    admin = true;
    Content = <SpaceAdmin />;
  } else if (path == '/profile' || path == '/profile/') {
    profile = true;
    typeContent = <ProfileContent />
  } else if (path == '/profile/comments' || path == '/profile/comments') {
    profile = true;
    Content = <ProfileSpace />
  } 
  

  return (
    <div>
      <div className='page-content' style={{ maxWidth: !admin ? '980px': '800px'}}>
        <div className='profile-page tx-13'>

          {(!profile || admin) ?  <Cover admin={admin}  profile={profile}/> : <CoverProfile admin={admin}  profile={profile}/> }

          {Content}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Spaces;
```

For now the conditional rendering is working perfectly. But as a newbie in React my question is, **is this the right thing to do or is there any other better method ?**

For now I'm afraid that I will need to add a custom `/:id` later to the paths and the conditions might not work.

Comment: I would replace the if else's with a react-router switch. It's specifically made for the problem you're trying to solve if I understood your question correctly. https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch

Comment: @isherwood Thank you very much sir, I will look into that.

Comment: Wasn't me. You're welcome, though.

Comment: Check this link (duplicate ?) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69470599/unable-to-hide-some-components-from-some-specific-routes/69472006#69472006

Comment: @MB_ So you are suggesting to use Switch insead of the ifs ?

Comment: @AlyaKra I suggest using useLocation. The switch case condition is a solution... It's up to you to see if it works well with your app.

Comment: @MB_ I see. But when I try to use `useLocation` I have an undefinded error and I don't have any idea why ? Also is there a difference between `match.urrl` and `location.pathname` ?

Comment: @AlyaKra You have a error because you use `useLocation` in App.js (the component where you created your routes)... You need to use it in components that change based on the pathname. (`match.url` and `location` => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47762475/what-exactly-is-match-url-in-react-router)

Comment: @MB_ Yes you are absolutely correct ! I was using it in App.js. But the problem with using it in components that change based on the pathname is that I need to repeat the same code again and again. Or could I create a pathname component and call it ?

Comment: @AlyaKra Yes, you can create a component with a switch case condition that returns multiple components based on location for example and import it in your other components

Comment: @MB_ Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a config file where you declare all the routes available to you and after that, create a routes file and import all the paths from path.js and create a list containing objects having all the props of  which are - exact,component,path. In path,s value, call the paths you've imported from paths.js. what it will do is, it creates a good structure for you to deal with routing in general

Comment: Interesting ! So you are suggesting to create a sort of global variables ? I was planning to do that with Redux to declare all routes etc..

Comment: Yes, there are some variables that are often used in multiple components inreact, example - a route. Although we can write the path statically everytime we use router, but inling run, when our application beco.es large enough and we need to change some specific variable, it becomes really hard to change the value, this is why I always use global objects containing repeatable variable key value pairs, key being a name and value is the dates stored, in your example it will be a route path.